# From Angular 4 app, I am hiiting an API, which is returning a string, with '\n' in between

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

I am hitting an API from my angular 4 application, from a component.
Now, after hitting the API, I got a response. That response is a string, with "" around the text. Now this text has a '\n' character, like

"Start your search with a First and Last Name plus State.\n To have a wider search".

Now, the client said at \n I need to see a newline. I am trying to achieve that.

I created a pipe and replaced \n with \ (a website suggestion) - not worked
Replaced \n with a 
, surprise!!!, didn't work either.
In HTML, I write <div [innerHTML]='item.message | safeHTML'> - didnt work
safeHTML has DOMSanitizer, as john suggested (Its a pipe by the way)

```
item = {
        id: data.json().response[i].id,
        textMessage: data.json().response[i].textMessage
      };
```

Comment: Your question is not clear

Comment: Could you please give an example? I believe your issue is not about Angular, but rather how to process a string in Javascript. I'm down voting your issue for now, until you give more details.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to render a string as HTML, you need to inject angular's [DomSanitizer](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer) into your component and call the `bypassSecurityTrustHtml()` method. Otherwise, as a security precaution angular will render a text string as just text (escaping the HTML).

Example

```
constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

someRandomMethodOfYours() {
  item = {
        id: data.json().response[i].id,
        textMessage: this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHTML(data.json().response[i].textMessage)
      };
}
```

Comment: Thank you, John, but now \n is gone totally, but the new line still doesn't render.

Comment: @srikarbandla `\n` isn't valid HTML. In HTML newlines are made with a `<br>` tag. One idea: you could use `.replace()` on the server response to replace instances of `\n` with `<br>`.

Comment: I tried with br too, but to no avail. Finally I tried 
<div innerHTML="item.message"> and it worked, with <br> in the backend.